# Angular $http using json file works but using json file with $httpBackend is not working to display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can **fake** getting data from **json** file with using **$http**  but with $resource/ **$httpBackend**   **I don't get any results**

**$http.get (works)**

```
 $http.get('api/devices.json')
      .then(function (result) {

      ...//
```

Above works just fine but the $httpBackend will work with json inline , but not pointing at JSON file

**Controller file which calls the deviceResourceMock module**

```
deviceResource.query(function(data) {    
       vm.devices = data; 
    });
```

**deviceResourceMock module**

```
app.run(function ($httpBackend) {

    var devices = 'test.json';  // Put new json file in same directory

    // ABOVE DOES NOT WORK
```

This DOES work below though

```
var devices = {"Devices":  [
        {
            "DeviceId": 1,
            "DeviceStatus": "Leaf Rake",
            "id": "GDN-0011",
            "ha": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
            "Urt": "blah"
        }
]};
```

URL and WhenGet

```
var deviceUrl = "/api/devices";
$httpBackend.whenGET(deviceUrl).respond(devices.Devices);
```

**Thoughts on why it doesn't work?**

Answer (score 0):

Is "devices.Devices" function?

I think code should be like

$httpBackend.whenGET(deviceUrl).respond(function(method,url,data) {

```
return devices.Devices;
```

});

Comment: {"Devices": is how the data will be wrapped in that object ... its how the Web api is sending data,  thus it is needed to do `devices.Devices` with that code i showed,   it is valid JSON to wrap it   It is not a function.